# Casting const pointer to non-const pointer when using struct iovec

Tags: c, casting

`struct iovec` is defined in `<uio.h>` by the following way:

```
/* Structure for scatter/gather I/O.  */
struct iovec
  {
    void *iov_base; /* Pointer to data.  */
    size_t iov_len; /* Length of data.  */
  };
```

Now I do ugly casting from `const void*` to `void*`:

```
int send_frame_once( int fd, const struct iovec* iov, size_t iovlen );


int send_frame( int fd, const void* buffer, size_t len )
{
    struct iovec iov;
    iov.iov_base = (void*)buffer;       /* const iov cast */
    iov.iov_len  = len;
    return send_frame_once( fd, &iov, 1 );
}
```

Is that necessary kludge?
Or should I remove `const` keyword from declaration of `send_frame` function. Like this:

```
int send_frame( int fd, void* buffer, size_t len )
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you should keep it. `const` is not only meant for the compiler, but also for anybody reading your code. Even with the `void*` cast, you're still saying to readers "Trust me, I'm not touching your buffer!" and this is a valuable information that should not be discarded.

Comment: assuming send_frame does not alter the content of buffer in any way.

Comment: Indeed, this is what I am assuming here.

Comment: Yep, buffer is not modified.